# $\mathbb C$-dimension of vector space $\mathbb C\otimes_{\mathbb R}\mathbb C$

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules, tensor-products

> Let $\mathbb R$ be the field of real numbers, $\mathbb C$ be the field of complex numbers. Consider $\mathbb C\otimes_{\mathbb R}\mathbb C$ as a $\mathbb C$-vector space via $a(b\otimes c) :=
> ab \otimes c,$ for $a, b, c \in \mathbb C$. Compute the $\mathbb C$-dimension of this vector space.

I guess the dimension is 1 and a basis is $\{1\otimes 1\}$. Is it correct? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hint: what's the dimension as a vector space over $R$?

Comment: How would you get $1\otimes i$ as a multiple of that vector?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft By def. $i(1\otimes 1) = i\otimes 1 = 1\otimes i$, right?

Comment: No, you are tensoring over the reals, not over the complex numbers.

Comment: You mean, $x\otimes y \neq y\otimes x$ and bases are $\{1\otimes 1, 1\otimes i\}$

Comment: @MarkDickinson I guess dim = 4 over R, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly right.

Comment: @MarkDickinson can you write down the bases for me?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sometimes it is better to look at a more general situation. In fact, this makes it easier to see what is really going on.

> 1) Let $V$ be a $K$-vector space and let $L/K$ be a field extension. Then $L \otimes_K V$ carries the structure of a vector space over $L$ via (linear extension of) $\alpha(\beta \otimes x) = \alpha\beta \otimes x$.
>
> 2) If $\{b_1,\dotsc,b_n\}$ is a $K$-basis of $V$, then $\{1 \otimes b_1,\dotsc,1 \otimes b_n\}$ is an $L$-basis of $L \otimes_K V$.
>
> 3) We have $\dim_L(L \otimes_K V) = \dim_K(V)$.

In 1) you have to check that this scalar multiplication exists at all. Use the universal property of the tensor product ( = definition of the tensor product) for this.

For the proof of 2) there are several methods. I suggest that you prove more generally that the tensor product commutes with direct sums in each variable (since this is useful anyway); then the claim follows immediately.

Of course, 3) follows from 2).

In particular, we see that $\{1 \otimes 1, 1 \otimes i\}$ is a $\mathbb{C}$-basis of $\mathbb{C} \otimes_{\mathbb{R}} \mathbb{C}$.